# Model parts become transparent on export

Tags: modeling

https://pasteall.org/media/b/0/b0342e19dc0dece44989795b9586738d.blend

So I was making a toon-style model with glasses. She's supposed to wear high heeled pumps.
However, when I export it as a .fbx file and view it using any fbx file viewer,

- The left high heeled pump becomes transparent
- The lens of the right eye goes missing
- The pupil and iris of the left eye are nowhere to be seen

What is the problem with this model? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Check to make sure all your normals are facing outwards. Also, check and possibly disable the culling settings (backface and/or frontface), in the program you are importing the model to (this commonly happens with unity, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christopher said in the comment:

Click here on "Face orientation".

[image]

As you can see, as result, there are some red parts in your model. Red means: The face orientation is wrong. Blue is ok.

[image]

You can solve that by selecting that part of the model, TAB to go to edit mode, A to select all, then Mesh-> recalculate outside:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely try it!

Comment: you are welcome